# 2D numpy arrays replacing values according to occurrence

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have many 2D arrays 1161 x 1161 composed of 0,1,2,3 numbers. for instance one of them is composed in the following way:

521859  zeros  , 288972 ones  , 481471 twos ,  55619 threes.

I would like to find the fastest way to obtain the same array but where now the smallest number of occurrences are the zeros , the second number of occurences are ones and so on, giving the same array but now composed of:

55619 zeros, 288972 ones, 481471 twos , 521859 threes

If there is a very pythonic way it would be great of course

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could you a more concrete example of what you have and what you want?

Comment: In 1D would be like a =np.array([2,2,0,0,0,1,3,3,3,3])

"1" is the less occurring number, then it would be replaced by a "0"
 "2" is the second less occurring number (appears twice) then would be replaced  by  "1"
 "0" occurs three times so it would be replaced by "2"
 Etc 

Giving

a= np.array ([1,1,2,2,2,0,3,3,3,3])

Basically the less occurring number would become 0, the second less 1 and so on. I do not expect ambiguity in the case two numbers appear with same amount. Hopefully is clear and I'm not making confusion.

Comment: You are, indeed, confusing me. Without any concrete example of your samples I don't understand how are your 2D array structured. Are the numbers ordered randomly or do they follow a sequence? And in your output do you care for the replacements to be in their same order or not?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [np.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the unique elements and the counts, then build a dictionary where the keys are the old values and values the new. Finally apply it to the whole array using [np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

arr = np.array([2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3])

# get unique elements and counts
counts = zip(*np.unique(arr, return_counts=True))

# create a lookup dictionary value -> i where values are sorted according to frequency
mapping = {value: i for i, (value, _) in enumerate(sorted(counts, key=itemgetter(1)))}

# apply the dictionary in a vectorized way
result = np.vectorize(mapping.get)(arr)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1 1 2 2 2 0 3 3 3 3]
```

A, perhaps cleaner, alternative is to use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), to count and create the mapping dictionary:

```
# get unique elements and counts
counts = Counter(arr)

# create a lookup dictionary value -> i where values are sorted according to frequency
mapping = {value: i for i, value in enumerate(sorted(counts, key=counts.get))}
```